# Get input from cgi POST data

Tags: c++, post, input, cgi, scanf

This is my c++ code to retrieve html data with cgi.

```
char* fileContentLength;
int nContentLength;
fileContentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");

if(fileContentLength == NULL)   
    return -1;      

nContentLength = atoi(fileContentLength);   

if(nContentLength == 0) 
    return -1;

data = (char*) malloc(nContentLength+1);

if(data == NULL)    
    return -1;

memset(data, 0, nContentLength+1);  
if(fread(data, 1, nContentLength, stdin) == 0)  
    return -1;

if(ferror(stdin))
```

After executing this code, i got the below result to the variable "data".

> f0=fname0&l0=lname0&f1=fname1&l1=lname1&f2=fname2&l2=lname2&f3=&l3=

Here f0,l0,f1,l1 are name of the input box of the HTML page. From this string i need to separate the values like fname0, lname0,fname1,lname1 and so on. I used sscanf function. but i could not retrieve the correct result. How can i assign the values from the above string to a local variable called firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 5):

Check out e.g. the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) function. Use it in a loop to split at the `'&'` to get all the key-value pairs into a vector (for example). Then go though the vector splitting each string (you can use `strtok` again here) at the `'='` character. You can put the keys and values in a `std::map`, or use directly.

For an even more C++-specific method, use e.g. [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) instead of `strtok`. Then you can put keys and values directly into the map instead of temporary storing them as strings in a vector.

**Edit:** How to get the last pair

The last key-value pair is not terminated by the `'&'` character, so you have to check for the last pair *after* the loop. This can be done by having a copy of your string, and then get the substring after the last `'&'`. Something like this perhaps:

```
char *copy = strdup(data);

// Loop getting key-value pairs using `strtok`
// ...

// Find the last '&' in the string
char *last_amp_pos = strrchr(copy, '&');
if (last_amp_pos != NULL && last_amp_pos < (copy + strlen(copy)))
{
    last_amp_pos++;  // Increase to point to first character after the ampersand

    // `last_amp_pos` now points to the last key-value pair
}

// Must be free'd since we allocated a copy above
free(copy);
```

The reason we need to use a copy of the string, if because `strtok` modifies the string.

I still would recommend to you use C++ strings instead of relying on the old C functions. It would probably simplify everything, including you not needing to add the extra check for the last key-value pair.

Comment: There is a problem to get the value of last empty elements (f3 and l3). I need to know whether the value of elements are empty are not. But i could not do this using strtok function.

Comment: @SmithDwayne Updated my answer to include how to get the last pair.